# Powershell 3 How to Reference Local File

Tags: powershell-3.0

How do I get Powershell to recognize the scripts local path?

I have, for example "test.htm" in the same folder as test.ps1 which contains
    Get-Content .\test.htm

This is the error:
    Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\some username\test.htm' because it does not exist.

What is the proper way to reference a local file?

Comment: wakey wakey there are people answering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "local," you mean local (i.e. a peer) to the running script then you should the following technique:

```
$file = join-path $psscriptroot "test.htm"
```

`$psscriptroot` is the folder the currently executing ps1 file resides in.

Answer (score 0):

xOn's way would work. But I am curious as to why it didn't see the file when you used the full path?
Give this a try to see if you have the same issue. Make sure you use double-quotes.

Get-Content -path "\computername\C$\Users<User folder>\file\test.htm"